# Set form as $pristine, but keep current values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My use case is that I need to enable/disabled a save button based on if the user has changed the values of a form.

When the user clicks the save button (after making changes) an AJAX save will occur, and on complete of that the form needs to be considered "pristine" again, **but keep the current values**.

I figured setting `form.$pristine = true` would work, which it does the first time after clicking the button, but editing the values from there doesn't set `$pristine` to false.

Example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VX2R1bdGJFdzH3LEsNnB?p=preview

```
<form name="submitForm">
  <input ng-model="data.first" type="text" />
  <input ng-model="data.second" type="text" />
</form>
<button ng-click="saveForm()">Submit</button>
<div>Form pristine: {{submitForm.$pristine}}</div>

//In controller
$scope.saveForm = function(){
  $scope.submitForm.$pristine = true;
}
```

1. Is there another way of doing this?
2. If not, what do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried with `$setPristine()` instead of `$pristine`?

Comment: That resets the values to the initial values doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **FormController.$setPristine();**
>
> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Comment: I misunderstood what that was saying, and all the examples showed it resetting the form to it's original state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ng-submit on the form tag rather than using ng-click. ng-submit makes sure all viewmodel changes are committed before event handler for ng-submit is called. This will apply specially if you are using ng-options with ng-model where you might have set options to set model to update only after certain time or onblur.

you can also do set the value of form to pristine on submit in markup like this

Here is the updated code and plunker. note that ng-submit will not get called if form is not valid. This is another advantage of using ng-submit over ng-click.

```
  <form name="submitForm" ng-submit="saveForm();submitForm.$setPristine();">
      <input ng-model="data.first" type="text" />
      <input ng-model="data.second" type="text" />
       <button >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2bWvPm9xNoVPFKYUhdUM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I understand why ng-submit is better, but my setup includes multiple buttons that don't necessarily involve the form.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Devin. Did not realize you were using multiple buttons. Glad you found the answer.